# Creating multiple SQL connections to different database for web based game

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am creating a game that is estimated to have a significant amount of tables, so we have separated the types of data into 2 databases: "game data" and "player data".

We initially tried using a module to initiate the SQL call like this:

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');

    const sql_game = mysql.createConnection({
      port: port,
      host: "host",
      user: "user",
      password: "pass",
      database: "game_database",
    });

    module.exports = sql_game;

const sql_player = mysql.createConnection({
      port: port,
      host: "host",
      user: "user",
      password: "pass",
      database: "player_database",
    });

    module.exports = sql_player;
```

The problem here is that the second module would override the first SQL connection when it is imported, instead of when it is called with `mysql_data()`; which results in SQL reading from the incorrect database and giving this error :

> no such table

I resolved this issue by separating the SQL modules into 2 files. For some reason, I can `require` both modules at the top of the code and then I can use both of them interchangeably using `sql_data` and `sql_player`.

So my question: Is it possible to have both modules in the same file without disrupting the SQL connection of the first module? When they are in the same file the second module overrides the first complete and I can't access that database due to it always trying to access the second database no matter which constructor I call.

Comment: While the question itself is in no way related to MySQL, but only to exporting different modules, you should think about putting everything in the same database. "Too much tables" is a bad argument for splitting up

Comment: Maybe your right about the database structure, but I think the issue is directly related to sql because it calls the mysql.createConnection() function when the module is imported to the script so the second one is always used.

The game data will also be created elsewhere and imported regularly, i didn't want this to interfere with any player data unintentionally. 


It will also make it easier to backup this data and preserve only tables that contain all of the user account and player fields. What are your thoughts?

Comment: As suggested by @nico, you should probably add the tables to the same database. Afterwards, you can use a connection pool to increase performance of executing commands on the database. You find a detailed introduction in the [package guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections).

Comment: `"issue is directly related to sql because it calls the mysql.createConnection()"` - no, having an object named `sql` doesn't mean it is directly related to mysql. This object is only a representation. On the topic: i think you can just have two instances of `mysql`, then you can execute `createConnection` on any of that instances

Comment: You've gotta think like this. A person who only knows how to write SQL statements wouldn't be of any help here. Like the others suggested, you should just keep it to one database. I don't know how big your structure is, but if it's somewhere near 15-20 tables, you shouldn't split it up. It'd just be a waste of resources

Comment: its about 300 tables